# What is a delimiter in this chomp function?

Tags: c, string

I am trying to understand what the following code does

```
void chomp (char* string, char delim) {  
   size_t len = strlen (string);  
   if (len == 0) return;  
   char* nlpos = string + len - 1;  
   if (*nlpos == delim) *nlpos = '\0';  
}
```

what is a delimiter?. Does the fourth line basically saves the last character in the string?

Answer (score 2):

If the last character of the string matches delim, then that characters position in the string (*nlpos) is assigned a zero byte, which effectively terminates the C string one position closer to the beginning of the string.

I *think* that the term chomp became popular with Perl that often trimmed off the terminating newline when doing line by line processing.

Answer (score 0):

The delimiter is the newline character.
Then string length is counted and type set to length (size_t formats lenghth into a ISO defined type that represents size).
Length of string is checked for zero (0) length and then returns to calling routine if true

Answer (score 0):

This code will cut away the delimiter in a string (can be a buffer) and put null character(`\0`) at the end.
The fourth line will store the last char in the string and replaces it with the null character. 
Delimiter is sequence of characters used to specify a boundary in plain text or region. Hence it will come at the end.
The NULL character is used in C style character strings to indicate where the end of the string is.